# psycopg2 DatabseError could not receive data from sever: Software caused connection abort

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I use the psycopg2 package to receive data from the sever. The data have more than 500 thousand rows. The error occurs at the 492349 rows. Why?

I googled this question and find the similar question on the website: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20060311110727.7E26BF0A01@svr2.postgresql.org

Is the size of file the problem? My file already reached 13.1M.

Comment: You need to look in the PostgreSQL server logs to see why the query terminated. Please also mention your PostgreSQL version - `select version()`.

Comment: @CraigRinger The PostgreSQL version is 9.2. Sorry I do not know how to find the history logs. I only find the logs today on the 'server status' in pgAdmin III. The specific error message in Python is 'DatabaseError: could not receive data from server: Software caused connection abort (0x00002745/10053)'.

Comment: That's a *client side* error, though. You need the *server* logs. They're in `c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data\pg_log` by default, assuming you installed to the default location. More correctly it's `%PROGRAMFILES%\PostgreSQL\9.2\data\pg_log`. Look in the log files.

Comment: @CraigRinger I already checked the log files in this directory. But the log file at the day when the error occurred contains nothing. Could it be the disconnection of network that leaded to this error? The database is at another computer. Thanks.

Comment: @CraigRinger I checked the log files at the server computer and found the log: 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.' and 'unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction'. I find the similar question at http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/dcc563d10711091441v24fba20fq275ac75f22f5636e@mail.gmail.com Maybe it's really beacuse of the network disconnection. Right?

Comment: That sounds like transient network issues, yes.